# Flutter: add animation to a list of animated container

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, animatedcontainer

I have a list of animatedContainers that get displayed based on their list index. I'd like to add animation fade-in/fade-out when switching between them. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: try this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_animations

Comment: can you include more details, what are you trying to archive?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.